# Add github url in jenkins blue ocean view

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-blueocean

When i run a job in jenkins and view it in the blue ocean view it shows me the short git hash on the top left. I would like this hash to be clickable and link to the github page of that particular commit. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

This is the hash i'm talking about.

Comment: I would be surprised as Blue Ocean recently came out of beta

Comment: Is there another way of quickly getting to the commit from this view?

Comment: Yes, there is an icon that I have posted in the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in Blue Ocean and we aim to have it fixed for the 1.2 release. Watch [this ticket](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45011) for updates.

Answer (score 0):

The icon with the box and arrow should be in the top right corner and allow you to go to the old UI to view more details on that build.

[image]

Comment: I was aware of this button but it just brings me back to the old interface. There i still need to find a clickable link that brings me to the github page of the branch/PR. I can find the git hashes and branch names, but nothing that i can click directly

Comment: ah yes, sorry I totally had misunderstood. I have been trying to find a way to do this in general: Github, Gitlab, Bitbucket. No luck.